# Stretching the chart with the highstock mouse

Tags: highcharts

Hello everyone how do I stretch the graph with the mouse along the Y axis?

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what do you have in mind... Would you like to trigger a zoom while clicking and panning the Y axis?

Comment: Zoom with the mouse on the Y axis

Comment: Would you like to achieve something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w8gfuy16/